# Modify content between two specific words in R

Tags: r

I want to modify the text between `<title> & </title> and <p> & </p>`. Also, it can repeat multiple times in the data.

```
<title>  DTC Descriptor </title>
<p>This diagnostic procedure supports the following DTC:</p>
<title>  Conditions for Running the DTC  </title>
<p>This is good</p>
```

Required output:

```
<title>DTC Descriptor</title>
<p>This diagnostic procedure supports the following DTC:</p>
<title>Conditions for Running the DTC</title>
<p>This is good</p>
```

I have found the trim function but I need to apply the function between the tags only.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two options - assuming `html` contains your example text:

```
library(XML)
doc <- htmlParse(html, asText = TRUE)
invisible(lapply(getNodeSet(doc, "//text()"), function(txt) xmlValue(txt) <- xmlValue(txt, trim = TRUE) ))

doc
# <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
# <html>
# <head><title>DTC Descriptor</title></head>
# <body>
# <p>This diagnostic procedure supports the following DTC:</p><title>Conditions for Running the DTC</title>
# <p>This is good</p>
# </body>
# </html>

cat(gsub("(<[^>]+>)\\s*(.*?)\\s*(</[^>]+>)", "\\1\\2\\3", html))
# <title>DTC Descriptor</title>
# <p>This diagnostic procedure supports the following DTC:</p>
# <title>Conditions for Running the DTC</title>
# <p>This is good</p>
```

Comment: `\\1` is the part captured by the 1st brackets, `\\2` by the 2nd ones and so on. E.g. `sub("a(bc)d(12)3", "\\1\\2", "abcd123")` yields `bc12`.